# Handling uncaught exception on page load with Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, uncaught-exception

I am trying to create a page exception handler using Primefaces 6.1. I am trying to avoid the SCA Fortify audit "Overly Broad Catch" vulnerability of having a "try {} catch (Exception e) {}" in my code so I cannot use a filter.

I've setup `<p:ajaxExceptionHandler />` which works well handling any exceptions thrown by actions on the page but not for exceptions thrown in the viewAction code executed under f:metadata on page load.

I've setup error-page on web.xml to redirect to error.xhtml which redirects correctly but I am not able to display the error message or stack trace with the following attempts.

error.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
>

<h:body>

<div id="incepPageBody">
  <h1> An error occurred</h1>
  #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}


  #{exception.message}
  #{exception.cause}

</div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
  <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```